# could not able to pass string values to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When trying to pass String value to the javascript function , Uncaught ReferenceError is thrown on the browser console.
Below is the sample code:

```
function mySampleTest(myId, comments){
    alert("myId " + myId);
    alert("comments : " + comments);
}

var myTest = function(value, rowIndex) {
    var myId = this.grid.getItem(rowIndex).MY_ID;
     var comments = this.grid.getItem(rowIndex).COMMENTS;
    return "<img src=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/image1.gif width=\"25\" height=\"25\" onClick=\"mySampleTest("+ myId +" , "+comments+")\">";
};
```

The JavaScript function `mySampleTest` is being called when the user clicks the image but it throws a JavaScript error when I pass the string **comments** to `mySampleTest` function. If I remove the comment parameters and just pass the `myId` to `mySampleTest(..)`, it works fine.
Please suggest how to pass string values to the JavaScript function.
I tried the below also, but didn't work.

```
 return "<img src=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/image1.gif width=\"25\" height=\"25\" onClick=\"mySampleTest("+ myId +" , \'' + comments + '\')\">";
```

Comment: what is the exact error? What does browser source version look like? If this is in a js file none of your server code will be compiled.

Comment: Does the error tell you a specific line or part of the code that causes it?

Comment: How does your browser render your img html snippet?

Comment: In all browsers below is the error message displayed: Uncaught ReferenceError: comments is not defined.

Comment: @Jasen - i'm using dojo grid, and onclick of the image inside the grid mySampleTest should be called bu passing the ID and comments to the javascript function. but when i pass string value i.e.,comments its throwing unReferenced error as said above. But if i pass only ID it succeeds. Thanks.

Comment: can you try this?  return "<img src=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/image1.gif width=\"25\" height=\"25\" onClick=\"mySampleTest('"+ myId +"' , '" + comments + "')\">";

Comment: When or in response to what event is `myTest(value, rowIndex)` called? Not sure there's enough information to  zero in on the cause of the error. You can leverage the power of jQuery to lay out a better approach **which will help you avoid some of the inherent issues with inline JS**. ...Wait .. you're using dojo too?

Comment: @Sushil - That is most likely the answer and probably belongs in an actual answer.

Comment: thanks @JDB. I believe his html is not getting rendered properly and hence the error. if he can just add a single quote before and end of the variable then it should work.

Answer (score 3):

As a professor once told me, much of writing code involves "being the computer".

Consider your function's output for a moment and you should see the issue pretty quickly:

```
<img src=whatever/your/context/path/is/images/image1.gif
     width="25" height="25"
     onClick="mySampleTest(12345, this is a comment)">
```

Your javascript is invalid:

```
mySampleTest(12345, this is a comment)
```

It should be:

```
mySampleTest(12345, 'this is a comment') // <--- notice the quotes
```

Which would translate all the way back to:

```
return "<img src=\"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/image1.gif\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\" onClick=\"mySampleTest('"+ myId +"' , '"+comments+"')\">";
```

Not to mention your `src` attribute really needs quotes.